# Binding of RowDefinition in FlipView different then binding of FlipView itself

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

> "MyGrid" has `DataContext` (assigned in code behind) with three public
>   properties:
>
> - 'Images'
> - 'h1'
> - 'h2'

Problem with the code below is that bindings to 'h1' and 'h2' are set to element of 'Images' collection but they should be set to binding of 'MyGrid'.

**my code**

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding h1}"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding h2}"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="AAA"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

How should I change 'h1' and 'h2' bindings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ElementName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify binding source:

```
 <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=DataContext.h1}"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=DataContext.h2}"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Row="0"
                               Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="AAA"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>
```